# Select images from Galley and add animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am creating an app where user selects images from gallery and selects a song of his/her choice and on click of a `button` '*Run Movie*'. Animation is played along with the song.
I am stuck at the animation playing part it plays only music and does not show any pictures.
I was successful playing animation with sound when I had images picked from drawables and specified in the `animation.xml`. Kindly guide me where I am making a mistake.

**Update**: I am able to get all image and song paths which user has selected.The only problem is with playing `frameanimation`.

Here is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation_sound);

        m_imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        imgPathArr = bundle.getStringArray("picsPath");
        songPath = bundle.getString("songPath");

        m_imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);

        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)m_imageView.getBackground();

        if(imgPathArr == null || imgPathArr.length == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please selct images first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            for(int i =0 ; i< imgPathArr.length; i++){

                    Log.d("Activity", imgPathArr[i]);
                    **frameAnimation.addFrame(
                            Drawable.createFromPath(imgPathArr[i]), 5000);**
            }
        }
```

*animation.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.9" >

</animation-list>
```

My code for Animation with sound when I am picking images from drawables

```
m_imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anim);
frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)m_imageView.getBackground();
```

anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pic1"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.9"
        android:duration="5000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pic2"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.9"
        android:duration="5000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pic3"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.9"
        android:duration="5000"/>    
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

*"I was successful playing animation with sound when I had images picked from drawables."*
If that worked for you then you can convert your **images** into [**`BitmapDrawable`**](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)s by using these methods

```
BitmapDrawable(Resources res, String filepath)
BitmapDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap)
```

from the documentation
***"A Drawable that wraps a bitmap and can be tiled, stretched, or aligned. You can create a BitmapDrawable from a file path, an input stream, through XML inflation, or from a Bitmap object."***

Use it like this

```
Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),filepath);
```

Hope it workes for you. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry but that did not help. I changed the code inside the for loop to `Log.d("Activity", imgPathArr[i]);
           Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),imgPathArr[i]);
           frameAnimation.addFrame(d, 5000);` Still same issue. No picture only audio.